# 'cordova build ios' create the app with 107 issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cordova, cordova-plugins

So my app i ready, i build the app with ionic v1 + cordova for android + ios by phpstorm and cordova cli.
The android working perfect!

but when i build the ios i open the `.xcworkspace` with the xcode and click on run and it's runnig on the iphone but with 107 issues.

And the issues it's from the plugins...

By the way for to success to running on ios I had to change the file `Podfile` to this:

```
# DO NOT MODIFY -- auto-generated by Apache Cordova
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'xxx' do
    project 'xxx.xcodeproj'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '~> 2.0.0'
    pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac'
    pod 'Google'
end
```

Someone have any idea how to fix that?
because, the push notification half working, i get the token but i don't get the notification on the phone, and yes i created all the certificate

[image]
[image]

my `ionic info`

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 
    Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1

local packages:

    Cordova Platforms : ios 4.5.2
    Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.3

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 6.0.0 
    Node       : v6.10.2
    npm        : 5.4.2 
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235 

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour, plugins are created by the community and not always up to date, this is why you are seeing so much deprecation warnings. But these are just warnings so they should not cause any trouble, they are just there to inform you that this should probably be fixed some time in the future before the deprecated methods get removed from the SDK.

If you want to *fix* all of them as you asked you will have to fork every plugin you use and replace the deprecated parts with its successors.

The problem with your push notifications is related to something else and you should as another question with more detailed information on that.